# How can I load module on demand?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know I can load modules (dependencies) in AngulrJS when bootstrap the app like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngSanitize',
    'ionic',
]);
```

I want to load some modules on the given controller, not global.

For example I have two controllers:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'partials/index',
      controller: IndexCtrl
    })
    .state('addPost', {
      url: '/addPost',
      templateUrl: 'partials/addPost',
      controller: AddPostCtrl
    });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I want to load `ui.tinymce` module in `AddPostCtrl` controller only, so I can use tinymce editor on `addPost` page. But I don't want to load `ui.tinymce` when I visit index page.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You nee to use AngularAMD, it lets you create angular objects on demand:

- http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/modules
- http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs

Comment: Is there any native solution in angular? I don't want to use RequireJS.

Comment: No, there isn't ES6 comes with something to work this around and the angular team said that they will aim for ES6 instead of just trying to fix ES5